# Android Studio 1.0.1 Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

I installed Android Studio version 1.0.1 and tried to import my project from eclipse to it it gave me the following error:

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
 Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
 File 1: E:\app3\app\libs\httpmime-4.3.jar
 File 2: E:\app3\app\libs\httpmime-4.3.jar``
```

I've tried to import my project with both using converting jars option to gradle and without converting them
i've searched a lot and tried solutions online but also didn't work
here is my build.gradle for my project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.FluoraPin.androidApp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

    android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':beyondAR_Framework')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.3.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/retrofit-1.8.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add `exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'` to your `packagingOptions`?

Comment: Have you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 12):

adding

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}
```

should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have duplication in dependencies:

```
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.6.jar')
```

class files in these 2 are the same