# Android Studio 1.5.1 Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE.txt commons-codec-1.9.jar...?

Tags: java, android, apache

commons-codec-1.9.jar... Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE.txt

```
> Error:Execution failed for task
> ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
> copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE.txt     File1:
> C:\Users\nandkishor.mewara\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder
> (2)\CityRetails\app\libs\commons-logging-1.2.jar  File2:
> C:\Users\nandkishor.mewara\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder
> (2)\CityRetails\app\libs\commons-codec-1.9.jar
```

Comment: This probaby means that both of these JAR files contain "META-INF/NOTICE.txt".

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30102953/14955

Comment: i am working on API 23 Your solution is not working...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download and Paste **'org.apache.http.legacy.jar'** file in **project/app/libs**

and add dependencies in **'build.gradle'**

if you have below line in your dependencies in gradle than don't add any other line for add jar file in your project.

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

**no need to import any commons-logging-1.2.jar file**