# Android Studio Dplicate file error in APK sdk_logo_1.png

Tags: android, error-handling, wikitude

I am using Android Studio with Wikitude Sdk Epson library. When I run the app I get a run error saying I have duplicate files. I have looked at the sources and can’t seem to locate any duplicate files. When I remove the wikitudesdk from the libs folder I get an error saying its unable to resolve dependencies, but two duplicate wikitudesdk.jar files listed. Perhaps my dependencies are incorrect? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

**ERROR:**

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK sdk_logo-1.png
>     File1: C:\Users\myusername\AndroidStudioProjects\Test2\app\libs\wikitudesdk.jar
>     File2: C:\Users\myusername\AndroidStudioProjects\Test2\app\libs\wikitudesdk.jar

**Build.Gradle File:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pmbi002.test2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile(name: 'wikitudesdk', ext: 'jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

**Errors after removing  compile(name: 'wikitudesdk', ext: 'jar'):**

```
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 21.31 secs
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: try removing `repositories { flatDir{ dirs 'libs' } }`.
because `complie fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` already includes the directory `libs`

Comment: When I remove that it gives me an error when it resyncs saying "Failed to resolve: :wikitudesdk:"

Comment: Well...there is almost nothing I can do with just "it gives me an error"

Comment: hmm I pasted the error text in the previous comment. This the first time I have posted a question myself. I have copied  the error below again. Thanks!                                                                                                  Error:Failed to resolve: :wikitudesdk:
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/pmbi002/AndroidStudioProjects/Test2/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: You can try to read this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282190/android-studio-1-5-1-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-notice-txt-commons-c

Comment: my wikitudesdk.jar file is in app/libs. I removed the line "Compile (name: 'wikitudesdk', ext: 'jar')"  since I have compile file tree. When I do this I get 61 run errors.  I updated my question with a copy of the errors above. thanks. I appreciate the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions! they helped me determine I actually had a couple of things wrong. I fixed the problem by removing "compile(name: 'wikitudesdk', ext: 'jar')" and chaging buildToolsVersion "24.0.0" to buildToolsVersion "23.0.3".